# Combinatorics - Integer sided triangles with integer median

Tags: combinatorics, triangles, combinatorial-geometry, integers

The original problem states: "Given a number N, how many integer-sided triangles $(a,b,c)$ with an integer median $m_{c}$ exist, provided that $a \leq b \leq c \leq N$?".

I've managed to get it down to a problem of combinatorics, but I'm having trouble expressing it mathematically. I'll refer to the function as $T(N)$ from now on.

Given a number N, how many ways are there to distribute a maximum of $3N$ indistinguishable balls into $3$ indistinguishable boxes $(a,b,c)$ in such a way that:

$a \leq b \leq c \leq N$

$a + b > c$

$d = 2a^2+2b^2-c^2$

$\dfrac {\sqrt{d}}{2}\:\in\mathbb{Z}$

By bruteforcing, I know that:

$c\mod 2 \equiv 0$

$a\equiv b\mod 2$

$N < 6 \rightarrow T(N) = 0$

$T(6) = 1 \rightarrow (5,5,6)$

$T(10) = 3 \rightarrow (5,5,6),(5,5,8),(6,8,10)$

$T(100) = 835$

$T(1000) = 149869$

$(a,b,c)\in T(N) \rightarrow (ka,kb,kc) \in T(N),\:k\in\mathbb{N},kc\leq N$

The last property is particularly useful I think, since it means that to figure out $T(N)$ I'd only need a much smaller initial set of triangles (how to find them, however, eludes me). To get these values I had to check almost $N^3$ combinations, so I obviously need a better way to calculate $T(N)$.

Comment: This is Project Euler #513.

Comment: @rogerl, It is! It doesn't seem too hard, I guess the trickiest part is translating the combinatorics problem into an algorithm, which I cannot figure out how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We must have:
$$ a\leq b\leq c\leq N,\quad 2a^2+2b^2-c^2 = (2d)^2 $$
but $c$ must be even, so $c=2C$ and:
$$ a^2+b^2=2(d^2+C^2).\tag{1}$$
Now it is useful to recall that the elements of the set $\square+\square$ are exactly the $n$s for which the multiplicity of every prime divisor of the form $4k+3$ is even. Moreover, $n=a^2+b^2$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ (also known as *primitive representation*) is possible if and only if there is no prime of the form $4k+3$ dividing $n$, and:
$$ \begin{eqnarray*}r_2(n) &=& \#\left\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:a^2+b^2=n\right\}\\&=&4\left(\chi_4 * 1\right)(n)\\&=&4\cdot\left(\sum_{\substack{d\mid n\\d\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!\!4}}}\!\!\!1\;-\!\!\!\sum_{\substack{d\mid n\\d\equiv 3\!\!\pmod{\!\!4}}}\!\!\!1\right),\end{eqnarray*} $$
so the solutions of $(1)$ may be found by considering all the couples $(a,b)$ such that $0\leq a\leq b\leq N$ and $a,b$ have the same parity, then checking if $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$ can be expressed as $d^2+C^2$ with $\frac{b}{2}\leq C\leq\frac{N}{2}$ by factoring $a^2+b^2$ and listing all the possible representations.

Cost: we have to test $\frac{N^2}{2}$ couples. The average value of $r_2(n)$ is $\pi$, so to list the representations and check them does not affect the asymptotic complexity in the average case. The only hard part is to factor every $a^2+b^2$: that can be done by pre-computing all the primes in the range $[1,2N^2]$ together with their (essentially unique) representation as $\square+\square$ in case they belong to the form $4k+1$. Or we may just check if $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}-C^2$ is a square by testing all the possible $C$s in the range $\left[\frac{b}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right]$. For such a task, a quadratic sieve is useful: for instance, if $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}-C^2\equiv 3\pmod{7}$ there is no chance that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}-C^2$ is a square, so for every couple $(a,b)$ the interval $\left[\frac{b}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right]$ can be sifted, leaving just a few $C$s that deserve to be checked for real. With the quadratic sieve, the expected running time should be around $O\left(N^{5/2}\right)$ and the memory needed $O(N)$.

> If memory is not an issue, we may also just put a type-1-mark $(a,b)$
>   on every integer of the form $a^2+b^2$ with $1\leq a\leq b\leq N$,
>   then put a type-2-mark $(d,C)$ on every number $\leq 2N^2$ of the form
>   $2(d^2+C^2)$ with $1\leq d\leq N,1\leq 2C\leq N$, then check, for
>   every number having both a type-1 and a type-2 mark, if $a\leq b\leq
>  c\leq N$ is fulfilled by pairing a type-1 and a type-2 mark. In this
>   case, both the average running time and the memory needed are
>   $\color{red}{O(N^2)}$.

Probably, by using hash tables we may also break the $O(N^2)$ barrier, since the  number of integers of the form $\square+\square$ or $2(\square+\square)$ in $[1,2N^2]$ is
$$ O\left(\frac{N^2}{\sqrt{\log N}}\right). $$

Comment: This is great! I think your formatting might be a little messed up though. Some of your symbols are replaced by squares which makes it a bit hard to follow the entire process.

Comment: @NicolásSiplis: it is not a typo - by $m=\square+\square$ I mean that $m$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares.

Comment: Ohh, that explains why when I checked the source code it said \squared. OK, I'll try your second algorithm to start, but I think it's not gonna be feasible since I need to solve the problem for N = 100000.

Comment: As expected, this implementation is considerably faster than the brute force approach, but it takes too long for values such as 100000 or higher. I still think there must be a combinatorics approach.

Comment: @NicolásSiplis: I would not bet that we can do significantly better than $O(N^2)$ since that is, more or less, the magnitude of the number of solutions.

Comment: The problem is from Project Euler #513, so supposedly the answer should be able to be calculated in 1 minute or less. For N = 100000 using this algorithm it's not gonna be possible.

Comment: I just realized my formulas were wrongly formatted... Half the square root of d is supposed to be an integer, not the square root of d/2. I'm terribly sorry, should've checked more carefully before posting.

Does that error alter the calculations significantly? I've check and it doesn't seem to, but maybe there's another property that can optimize the algorithm even further now?

Comment: I was just rechecking the formulas and realized that you put $2a^2+2b^2-c^2 = (2d)^2$. Shouldn't that be $2a^2+2b^2-c^2 = d$?

Comment: @NicolásSiplis: nope. In the first line I put $c=2C$ ($c$ must be even), hence $2a^2+2b^2-4C^2=4d^2$ leads to $a^2+b^2=2(C^2+d^2)$.

Comment: The length of the median is given by $\sqrt{\frac{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}{4}}$, hence the first equation $2a^2+2b^2-c^2=4d^2$ is right.

Comment: Yep, just got it a little mixed up. Well, the program's running and it should take about 1 day to finish, let's hope everything goes smoothly!

Comment: After much thought I haven't been able to get a direct formula to calculate the integer triangles with an integer median, so I'll just use your algorithm. It's gonna take a few days more than I thought but I guess that's not such a long wait. Once again, thanks!

Comment: *In re* your block quote comment: Note that the condition $a\leq b$ is always satisfied if you generate the set of squared sums as specified.