# Finding all solutions: $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I want to find all solutions to the problem of two squares equaling two other squares. $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2 \qquad b \le N$$Clearly, without loss of generality, I can assume that
$$gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1$$
and $c\le a \le b \le d$. But after that, I'm a bit stuck. I can see an $N^2$ solution doing a meet-in-the-middle algorithm but I'm not sure there isn't a better way to solve this. On a Diophantine equations website it listed this problem as something "which can be done completely" but didn't give a parameterization of HOW to do it completely. Is the meet-in-the-middle the best or is there some better way to go about this?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: It is not an exact duplicate but the same answer applies: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254318/combinatorics-integer-sided-triangles-with-integer-median/1254397#1254397

Comment: Maybe to use formulas $a^2+b^2=M^2 \Leftrightarrow a=2nm,\,b=n^2-m^2,\,M=n^2+m^2$ up to order $a,b$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Should I remove the post? I couldn't find anything similar so I asked. Also, I don't immediately see how the same answer applies but I'm willing to trust you.

Comment: @amcalde: the other problem asks for the solutions of $$2a^2+2b^2=c^2+d^2$$ such that $1\leq a\leq b\leq c\leq d$, and my answer shows that the meet-in-the-middle approach is more effective than other techniques, I am just too lazy to write down the same argument twice.

Comment: No worries @JackD'Aurizio, that's exactly what I was asking. I'll just stick with meet-in-the-middle. Thank you

Comment: There is in fact a solution of Euler of this problem showing that every solution can be written as $a=xy-zt$ $b=yz+xt$ and $c=yz-xt$ and $d=xy+zt$

Comment: @Elaqqad, So with $x,y,z,t$ coprime integers? Any thing else I should know? I'll try it out.

Comment: without assuming anything in $a,b,c,d$ other than the equation you will find $x,y,z,t$ this is the general solution. if you assumed that $a,b,c,d$ are coprime you will get some constraints on $x,y,z,t$ but not exactly that they are coprime

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153603/diophantine-equation-a2b2-c2d2/736164#736164

Answer (score 2):

This is easily solved by rearranging and factoring:
\begin{align}
a^2-c^2 &= d^2-b^2  \\
(a-c)(a+c) &= (d-b)(d+b).
\end{align}
If one of the factors is zero, than we have a *trivial* solution; one of the factors on the other side must also be zero, *etc.*

Assuming $a \ne \pm c$, we can find $g=\gcd(a-c,d-b)\ge 1$, say $a-c=gu$ and $d-b=gv$ for nonzero integers $u$ and $v$ with $\gcd(u,v)=1$. Now
\begin{align}
gu(a+c) &= gv(d+b)  \\
u(a+c) &= v(d+b).
\end{align}
Since $u$ and $v$ are coprime, we must have $a+c=kv$ and $d+b=ku$ for some nonzero integer $k$. Back-substituting will give you a parameterization (a.k.a. “complete solution”). From that point, it would be easy to apply the $N$ bound.

Bonus: This technique is equally effective for any equal sums-of-squares equation. See [Bradley’s paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3620159) for more details and examples.