# Does there exist a parallelogram such that all sides are integers?

Tags: diophantine-equations

> If there exists a parallelogram (not a rectangle) $ABCD$ such that $AB=CD=x$, $BC=DA=y$, $AC=z$, $BD=w$, do there exist postive distinct integers $x,y,z,w$ such that $x\geq y\geq z\geq w$?

I know we have $$2(x^2+y^2)=z^2+w^2$$

Comment: if x,y,z,w are distinct, the parallelogram can't be a rectangle anyway.

Comment: Can we have $x=y$?

Comment: $x\ge y\ge z\ge w$

Comment: $x\geq y\geq z\geq w$ clearly can't be true, since then $2(x^2+y^2)>x^2+y^2\geq z^2+w^2$.

Comment: must the vertices be labeled in that order? is the paralelogram convex?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127654/parametrization-of-solutions-of-diophantine-equation

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo *All* parallelograms are convex.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254318/combinatorics-integer-sided-triangles-with-integer-median

Comment: @individ That equation is slightly different, lacking the factor $2$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen  same equation. Put the right coefficients.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen If $x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2$ then $(z+w)^2+(z-w)^2=2(x^2+y^2)$ (an application of the Brahmagupta identity, really). Therefore solutions of the former give solutions of the latter.

Comment: Mustn't one of $z$ and $w$ be larger than both $x$ and $y$, contradicting $x\geq y\geq z\geq w$?

Comment: @md2perpe I missed that (it was only a comment when I posted).

Answer (score 1):

An integer greater than one can be written as a sum of two squares if and only if its prime decomposition contains no prime congruent to $3 (\mod 4)$ raised to an odd power. Thus there are such infinitely many integers without $x\geq y\geq z\geq w$. Even more simply $2(x^2+y^2)=(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2.$

But with the condition $x\geq y\geq z\geq w,$ no such quadruples.

Comment: But not always these are positive squares.

Comment: Yes. But consider $p=w^2+z^2.$

Answer (score 1):

For $x\leq y\leq z\leq w$ there is the following 
$x=68$, $y=85$, $z=87$ and $w=127$